# Excel VBE Unhide Module Code Is No Longer Visible

Tags: excel, vba, module, vbe

Using Excel 365.
I accidentally clicked to hide a module.
(right-click module >> select Hide)

All this appears to do is close the Project Explorer and Properties Explorer Windows
I clicked View Menu and selected those Panes and I can see all Code Modules.

However, I can no longer see anything in the Code Window.
It was grey for a long time, but I undocked and redocked the Project Viewer Pane.
Now the Code Window is white, but there is no visible code in any module.

To make it worse, I saved the file in a new folder with a new name - the file is only 10 KB. Earlier today when I looked at the file size it was 259 KB.

What, if any are my options to get all of my code modules back exactly as they were?

[image: Code Not Visible]

Comment: I saved a copy earlier with a new name. That new file is 259 KB - exaclty as expected. I made a copy of that file and I am opening the copy.

I opened the copy (myfile_7a.xlsm), but several other files also opened
myfile_v6.xlsm
x6.xlsm

This behavior is unexpected and nothing that I coded to happen.
What is going on here?

Comment: in the VBE IDE, click Window at the top, then click Cascade - does that make them reappear?

Comment: I closed all workbooks and closed Excel. I reopened version 7A. 7A shows as 259 KB. There is one empty worksheet in the workbook.

I tried to collapse all modules in Project Explorer and Expand again - I still cannot see any code in the code window.

I do have a reference set to VBE Extensibility, so I can run a bit of code to list all modules in their Sub and Functions. I tried to remove the Reference to the Library, but when I click on References, the Dialog simply disappears.

Comment: I was able to recover all code modules. I followed instructions from Microsoft Support
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53